# boxed only one equation among others in beamer

Tags: beamer, boxes, empheq

how can I get only boxed equation among others
I'm using `empheq` to align equation but I can't boxed only one equation among others.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usetheme{madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{boxed only one equation not all of them}
I would like to boxed only one equation among others.
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
D_{f}&=\mathbb{R}-\{3\}\\
D_{f}&=]-\infty;3[\cup]3;+\infty[
\end{empheq}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need `empheq` for that. Use the `\Aboxed` command, defined by `mathtools`. To have a correct spacing in the r.h.s. of the second equation, I suggest defining a `\openintvl` command with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`;

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usetheme{madrid}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\openintvl}{]}{[}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{boxed only one equation not all of them}
I would like to boxed only one equation among others.
\begin{align*}
D_{f}&=\mathbb{R}-\{3\}\\
\Aboxed{D_{f}&=\openintvl{-\infty;3}\cup\openintvl{3;+\infty} }
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that I've updated, as the initial spacing in the second equation was not good, using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`